# Many to many: NameError Exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models:

**group.rb:**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_groups
  has_many :users, through: :users_groups
end
```

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :users_groups
end
```

**users_groups.rb**

```
class UsersGroups < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
end
```

When I type `@group.users` in Rails' console, It throws an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Group::UsersGroup
```

When I change `UsersGroups` to `UsersGroup` in users_groups.rb I still get the same error.

I am using Rails 4.0.2. Is this a bug?

Comment: if you try to create a HABTM between two table you do not required the mediator model. also the table should be name `groups_users` as per the convention the table which comes first alphabetically should comes first in table name. visit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because rails expects you to follow its naming conventions, which for instance means that model names should be in singularis.

If you were to name your join table/model `UserGroup` (or `UsersGroup`) it would probably work, like this:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups
end

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Also, as someone already has pointed out, you don't really need a mediator model. You could just have rails create the join-table automatically. I do believe it's recommended to actually create the mediator table/model yourself though. It's a bit clearer to know what's going on if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a bug. You're not following the convention. A model has to be singular, but you're using plural for `UsersGroups`. It'll probably work if you change your model name to `UsersGroup`.

Comment: Actually, I change  I Change ```UsersGroups``` to ```UsersGroup`` `in ```users_groups.rb```, But still above error.

Comment: @user3160143 You also have to change the filename to `users_group.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

if you try to create a HABTM between two table you do not required the mediator model. also the table should be name `groups_users` as per the convention the table which comes first alphabetically should comes first in table name. visit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Answer (score 1):

if `UsersGroups` doesn't have logic other than provide a HABTM (no callbacks, validation or custom attributes) you can drop that class and replace the relations this way:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

And the join table has to be called `groups_users` as 'groups' comes first than 'users' alphabetically

```
create_table :groups_users do |t|
  t.belongs_to :group
  t.belongs_to :user
end
```

If you are going to put some logic and you need a class for that, you can use `has_many :through`. There you can call the join table UserGroup without any problem

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :users, through: :user_groups
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_groups
  has_many :groups, through: :user_groups
end

class UserGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```